# QGIS Report Slope Results

Tags: qgis, raster, statistics, slope

How could I report information about a raster result? In this case I have done slope analysis, and have reclassified it into 5 values for particular slopes. Now I am wondering if I can report information based in this, such as "X% of the site has a slope between 1:4 & 1:12". Or this could be for Aspect, "X% of the site faces NW-NE".

Does anyone know how to do this? Are there existing plugins I haven't found?

Answer (score 0):

You can run [**Zonal Statistics**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#zonal-statistics) and get the Sum of Pixels by Zone(Site).

This however doesn't account for different classes within the Raster; so you would have to create a different raster for each class [**Raster Calculator**](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#raster-calculator) and then run this Zonal Statistics for each one.

Answer (score 0):

1 Create a polygon covering the area of interest.

2 [Zonal Histogram](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#qgiszonalhistogram):

> Appends fields representing counts of each unique value from a raster
> layer contained within polygon features.

3 Create a Virtual Layer using DB Manager (Or Layer - Create Layer - New Virtual Layer" with the query:

```
SELECT  *,
        100.0*"HISTO_1"/("HISTO_1"+"HISTO_2"+"HISTO_3") AS Class_1_perc,
        100.0*"HISTO_2"/("HISTO_1"+"HISTO_2"+"HISTO_3") AS Class_2_perc,
        100.0*"HISTO_3"/("HISTO_1"+"HISTO_2"+"HISTO_3") AS Class_3_perc
from "Output zones"
```

Replace "Output zones" with the name of your Zonal histogram output, adjust the column names, and add/remove rows for all your classes

[image]
(I know they dont sum to 100, I got the column names mixed up)